# How to calculate score while using SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, cross-validation

I am new to machine learning, I am a bit confused by the documentation of the sklearn on how to get the score while using `sklearn.svm.SVC`.

This is my code

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.30)

for _c in [0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4]:
    svm=SVC(C=_c,kernel='linear')
    svm.fit(x_train,y_train)
    result=svm.predict(x_test)
    print('C value is {} and score is {}'.format(_c,svm.score(x_test,y_test)))
```

**This is the output**

```
C value is 0.4 and score is 0.0091324200913242
C value is 0.6 and score is 0.0091324200913242
C value is 0.8 and score is 0.0091324200913242
C value is 1.0 and score is 0.0091324200913242
C value is 1.2 and score is 0.0091324200913242
C value is 1.4 and score is 0.0091324200913242
```

I see all the score are same, my question how to determine the best score of my model?

1. should I pass the predicted value to svm.score y value i.e.

   ```
   result=svm.predict(x_test)
   svm.score(x_test,result))
   ```
2. should I pass the x_test and y_test value i.e.

   ```
   svm.score(x_test,y_test))
   ```

Comment: You are not changing SVC's `c` parameter in the loop, it is always 0.6, that's why you always get the same score

Comment: please see my edited question, i changed it as you have pointed out and still my result is not getting changed

Answer (score 1):

To your question:

1. It is wrong, you cannot compare features `x`with your target `y`
2. Same mistake as in 1.

you have to use:

```
for _c in [0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4]:
    svm=SVC(C=_c,kernel='linear')
    svm.fit(x_train,y_train)
    result=svm.predict(x_test)
    print('C value is {} and score is {}'.format(_c,svm.score(y_test,result)))
```

This will compare your original target values `y_test` with your predicted values `result` . That is the idea of testing, you test your prediction against original values to see how good/bad your prediction is.